# How to save configuration data in a file

Tags: python, module

I do have the module `config.py` which has vars in it that indicates configuration data.

For example:

```
logfile_enable = True
logfile_name = "debug.log"
logfile_maxsize = 100*1024 # 100KB
logfile_backupCount = 1
```

Then I can just `import config` in every project script, and access data through `config.VAR` (`config.maxsize` for example).

I do want to save the changes to the module once the application is closed.
I thought about pickling the `__dict__` of the module and somehow set it back on startup, but I seem to fail doing it, as you can't call `__dict__` from the module itself.

I don't want to use a class and a dict in it. I think that the `config.VAR` syntax is much clearer in the script, and I don't want to initialize a new class object in every import.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the standard library [ConfigParser module](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) for this purpose, and then had a global config object, so in all your files you say `from config import config` where `config` is an instantiated `ConfigParser` object which you can read stuff from load from a file and save to a file.

Comment: The data saving itself is no problem, I can choose between a `ConfigParser` or a `pickle`. It both cases I need to get the vars list/dict somehow. Is there a way to get a module vars from the module itself?

Comment: If you don't like the config.get("section","vaue") syntax then wrap the `ConfigParser` object in a class so you can say `from config import config` then config.value.  It is a bit more work, but won't leave you in the world of pain if you start messing with the module dictionary!